# New to Ubuntu Is it possible to install Ubuntu on my Compaq 420 windows 7 pc?

Tags: system-installation

my DXDIAG file info:

```
  Machine name: HP-PC    Operating System: Windows 7 Ultimate 32-bit 
  Language: English (Regional Setting: English) System Manufacturer: Hewlett-Packard
  System Model: Compaq 420
  BIOS: Default System BIOS
  Processor: Intel(R) Core(TM)2 Duo CPU     T6570  @ 2.10GHz (2 CPUs),
  Memory: 2048MB RAM Available OS Memory: 1976MB RAM
  Page File: 1294MB used, 2657MB available
  Windows Dir: C:\Windows    DirectX Version: DirectX 11 DX Setup Parameters: Not found    User DPI Setting: Using System DPI  System DPI Setting: 96 DPI (100    percent)    DWM DPI Scaling: Disabled
  DxDiag Version: 6.01.7601.17514 32bit Unicode
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes mate

Linux supports all type of computers
Just make sure to download a 32bit version of ubuntu and free space for the dualboot in case you want it

Comment: Intel(R) Core(TM)2 Duo is a 64-bit CPU. For older 64-bit hardware, particularly if using an old integrated graphics the recommendation should NOT be neither 32/bit nor Ubuntu, Kubuntu, Ubuntu-GNOME or any 3D resources hungry DEs. 64-bit versions of Lubuntu, Xubuntu or other *light* variant are in order. But please use the duplicate above instead of answering. Add your personal answer to *that* question if you feel you can post a better answer than the ones already there.